# iPad Chrome has wrong height

Tags: html, css, ios, google-chrome, ipad

iPad Pro(11-inch), iPadOS version: 16.6.1, Chrome version: 116.0.5845.177
I create a simple html and try to run on iPad. Although I set the height to 100vh, there is a vertical scrollbar on the right, and I could scroll down to a total empty page. It seems like the total height is more than 200vh.
The web page works on Safari, but not work in iPad chrome.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color: green; height: 100%; width:100%;">This is a div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `min-height: -webkit-fill-available;` could be causing this issue.

You can try:

```CSS
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

If that doesn't work try it with `height: 100%;`

```CSS
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You could also try using browser-specific CSS properties to target Chrome specifically if the issue persists:

```CSS
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  /* Target Chrome on iOS */
  body {
    height: 100vh;
  }

  html {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I tried all three options, none worked

Comment: What is your exact screen resolution on your tablet?

Comment: 2388-by-1668-pixel resolution at 264 pixels per inch (ppi)
Got this information from https://support.apple.com/kb/SP843?locale=en_US

Comment: Try this [code](https://codepen.io/schtucks/pen/yLGbPrL) here. I restructured your entire html page. Maybe this helps!

Comment: After clear all Browsing data, it works. Werid... thanks for your help